# Force browser to clear cache when changes has been added or updated in Visual web-part control file

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, visual-web-part, user-controls, cache

I am working on visual web-part (SP 2016 on-prem) and it's control (ascx) file has HTML, CSS and jQuery code.
When I made any changes inside it, then changes are not reflecting at end user's or client machine. user have to clear the browser history or refresh forcefully by pressing Ctrl + F5 which is a temporary fix.

There are some requirement, because of that I can't move my jQuery, CSS or HTML code to a separate file, otherwise I'll add [cache busting](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting) concept, but my case is different here.

Is there any possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use IIS Cache-Control settings (HTTP Response Headers) or web.config (clientCache) settings to disable caching on the Visual Web Part folder level.

Some concrete steps and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642954/iis7-cache-control).